# App crash after modifying a structure

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble with a project that compiles ok but crashes on startup before even reaching InitInstance().
This happens after I added a string to a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
long            nChannelIndex;
TCHAR           szChannelName[32];
DWORD           dwStartTime;        // time_t
DWORD           dwPlaytimeMs;       // msecs
TCHAR           szStepName[32];
TCHAR           szFilename[MAX_PATH];
long            nLenMs;
TCHAR           szStepDescr[64];
DWORD           dwSessionID;
TCHAR           szLocationName[32];
long            bInsertion;
BOOL            nOrigin;        // 0= local,  1= cuemaster,
TCHAR           szList[32];
TCHAR           szFSPath[MAX_PATH];  <<  THIS HERE IS THE PROBLEM
}REPORTDATA, *LPREPORTDATA;
```

When I added the last member of the structure the problem began. If I reduce the array size to a smaller number (say 12) the app works ok.

I get a crash in chkstk.asm - around this code:

```
; Find next lower page and probe
cs20:
sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.
jmp     short cs10
```

I am compiling a 32 bits c++ application on windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits. Msvc 2010.

I am not asking to have my code debugged. Just including code to show what triggered the crash and where it happened.

Any Ideas?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have a large array of these structures as a local variable?

Comment: Impossible to diagnose from the posted code. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please. At the *very* least, post the code using/accessing this monstrocity.

Comment: Impossible to post a SSCCE because this application IS a monstruocity - as you said. It's a multithreaded digital video server capable of handling commercial insertion in up to 128 channels. And, as I said earlier, there's no accessing this data, the app crashes as soon as it launches. @MarkRansom is probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the module where the crash occurs `chkstk.asm` is a clue to what is happening. It's checking the stack allocation to make sure you haven't run out. It appears you *have* run out, by adding a large new element to your structure. It's very hard to run out of stack space with a single structure, so I assume you have an array of them. Local variables are what get allocated to the stack, so the problem is likely a local variable containing an array of these structures.

You can give your program more stack space with the [`/F` compiler switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx).

You could also use a `vector` instead of an array, which will allocate the space in the heap instead of on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true it's impossible to diagnose correctly with what information you've provided, it's a fairly safe assumption that you've overflown the stack. As Mark Ransom says you probably have a large local array of these on the stack somewhere.

EDIT:
The stack, where local variables are usually, but not necessarily, stored is a finite size inside your application, it is usually allocated when the thread is created and is configurable with OS functions like pthread_attr_setstacksize, one option if you are running out of stack space is to enlarge the stack on the thread you are working on, although it's usually not a good idea.

The easiest and safest solution to the problem is to allocate the large data on the heap with a call to C malloc or C++ new. The heap is generally many orders of magnitude larger than the stack but requires explicit C free or C++ delete when you are done with the data, it will not be cleared up after the local scope ends like a stack variable will.

Beware, the main concern with heap variables is that they will leak, say for example, through a function exiting early via a throw. This is why it is recommended that when dealing with heap objects that you use a std::unique_ptr to store it, This conforms to the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) concept.

Comment: The app may have 24, 48, 96 or 128 of these depending on the licenses bought by the client, so yes. How can I go about this?

Comment: I will expand my answer